# Solr search entire index but only return the lowest level descendents

Tags: solr, hierarchy, solr8

I am completely lost at getting the Solr ecosystem under my belt...maybe because the data structure I am dealing with is fundamentally difficult for handling in Solr correctly.  I am trying to index documents/entries of a hierarchical classification system (NAICS: https://www23.statcan.gc.ca/imdb/p3VD.pl?Function=getVD&TVD=1181553).

The structure is a such:

- 11-Agriculture

  - 111-Crop Production

    - 1111-Oil seed and Grain farming

      - 11111-D Soybean Farming

        - 111110-Soybean Farming
        - 111111-Other bean farming
      - 11112-Wheat farming

        - 111120-Wheat farming

What I want is to index the entire structure in Solr (using whatever means is recommended, i.e. nested documents, or some other category/path variable solution etc) so that when a user searches and their search terms are too broad to match at lower levels of the structure and instead match higher up in the structure that all descendants are still matched and returned instead.
For example, user searches 'oil seed farming' and a hit is returned for document representing 1111-Oil seed and Grain farming.  What I want instead is to just return last leaf descendants of that entry (111110, 111111, 111120) as though they were matched in the first place.  How does one accomplish this in Solr or what are the options?  The ultimate goal is to filter the structure to lowest leafs only based on the user query.

edit:
based on suggestions received this is the approach I worked out.

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/NAICS/query -d '{
  "query": "{!join from=ANCESTOR_PATH to=DESCENDANT_PATH}NAICS:1111",
  "facet": {
    "TREE_NODES": {
      "type": "query",
      "q": "LEVEL:5",
      "facet" : {
        "TREE": {
          "type": "terms",
          "field": "DESCENDANT_PATH",
          "limit":-1
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index each lower leaf as a document. For each document, include all the terms in the parents, all the way up to the root. This will give you something like:

```
{
  "id": "111110",
  "name": "Soybean Farming",
  "path": "11-Agriculture/111-Crop Production/1111-Oil seed and Grain farming/11111-D Soybean Farming",
  "categories": [
    "11-Agriculture",
    "111-Crop Production",
    "1111-Oil seed and Grain farming",
    "11111-D Soybean Farming"
  ]
}
```

This will allow you to search for any terms against the `categories` field, and if you use a `string` field (or a [path hierarchy tokenizer field](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/tokenizers.html#Tokenizers-PathHierarchyTokenizer)) for the `path`, you can also do exact matches to look up a hierarchy if you want.

Comment: I had thought about this method, but two issues I see is that it duplicates information in the index that I would like to avoid if possible and the other issue I see is that I will be limiting the number of returned records to the application and relying on facet counts to determine what to display to the user.

Comment: Duplicating information depending on how you want to use it and how you want it analyzed is one of the core concepts of document oriented search engines search as Lucene. Unless you have _very_ particular requirements and an exceptionally large dataset, it's a perfectly valid (and suggested) strategy for achieving specific goals. Facet counts should be fine; depending on what you need of course, but the path tokenizer will index one token for each level of the path, giving you a facet that applies to every level of the hierarchy.

Comment: I have had some success on this....I have indexed two additional fields, ancestor_path and descendant_path.  I then query as such: q={!join from=ANCESTOR_PATH to=DESCENDANT_PATH}NAICS:"1111" and it will return documents with naics=1111 plus any documents that are descendants of them.  So I have the correct documents being returned now, but for facet counts it is not what I want.  Facet counts should be based on only leave nodes and unique values in descendant_path but I have no idea how to accomplish this.

Comment: I can filter out all levels except the lowest level from the result set easily and this fixes the facet counts, however what I really would like is to keep them in the result set but filter them out only for the calculation of the facet counts without impacting the main query...

Comment: You could use just `NAICS:1111*`, since anything starting with `1111` should be a descendant, couldn't you? For faceting you can [use the JSON facet API](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/json-facet-api.html#query-facet) and create a query facet that selects the leaf nodes, and then a subfacet that splits those into their appropriate buckets based on a field.

Comment: Yes I can do that, however on the client interface there will be only one search box to allow entering of keywords which can be a NAICS code or keywords.  The search will be done against NAICS codes, NAICS titles, descriptions, and example activities.  I will look into the JSON facet API, thanks again for your guidance.

Comment: If you use the `categories` field as shown above with a tokenizer, it should work as you expect - 1111 would be a separate token for all categories where it's part of the hierarchy. But check out the JSON Facet API - I think it should solve what you're looking for.

Comment: one of the extending issues of the NAICS codes is that there are three root nodes that are represented as ranges (i.e. 31-33, 44-45, and 48-49).  When a user enters '44-45' it will be tokenized as 44 and 45 which means it will match to both 44 and 45 sub category/NAICS but not the root node '44-45'.  I was thinking to keep the category/NAICS code in a separate field that is not tokenized (string) separate from the title which will be subject to tokenization and other parsing.

Comment: accepted this answer as it ultimately got me to a viable solution, see original question for final solution that was used.